# Bootstrap carousel not displaying in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Hi I have installed bootstrap using the standard npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap command and implemented the carousel code from the bootstrap site but i don't get the carousel. Images are displaying one by one here's my code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
**import {Carousel} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';**
import CleanHands from '../Images/cleanhands.jpg';
import Heroes from '../Images/heroes.jpg';  

class ImageCarousel extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
                <Carousel>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src={CleanHands}
                        alt="First slide"
                        style={{width:"40px", height:"40px"}}
                        />
                    </Carousel.Item>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src={Heroes}
                        alt="Third slide"
                        />
                    </Carousel.Item>

                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src={CleanHands}
                        alt="Third slide"
                        />
                    </Carousel.Item>
                </Carousel>

        );
    }
}

export default ImageCarousel;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import bootstrap css in your App.jsx:

```
// Importing the Bootstrap CSS
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

I can see you have it in your carousel but you should import it in App. Also, you need to install bootstrap as the doc says in its [Getting Started section](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/).

That what i needed for the carousel to work [on my repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bootstrap-examples-n8u3re?file=index.js)

Comment: I tried your suggestion it still didn't work for me i added in app.js, index.js and the js file where i import it still it is not working images are showing one by one
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

could you please help me solve this i've been trying it for close to 2 hours now

Comment: It's working like a charm on my stackblitz even when copying your whole component. try importing the css as the last import of your app.js. Also, what is your react, react-dom, bootstrap, react-bootstrap versions please ? If you could reproduce your bug (A stackblitz or codeSandbox would be perfect) or provide all the code of your project to reproduce it that would be great

Comment: "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react": "^16.13.1",

These are the versions i use

i also get  warning but i don't know if it is related to this issue
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/content.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Nothing is wrong here so I don't know what could makes it break. can you try to reproduce your bug on codesandbox please ? (material-ui does not works well on stackblitz). You can also try to uninstall material-ui, maybe it provoque some collisions between packages

Comment: i tried with a new workspace it worked i don't know what's the problem i uninstalled using the npm uninstall bootstrap react-bootstrap command and then installed again then also i get same issues.

Comment: Try installing material-ui on your new workspace to see. I'm pretty sure your problem come from one of your package